# Ng-Repeat Angular + Touch Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, keyboard

i'm making a table with some field, with the option to add new rows. At the end, i will print all the field. 
The application i am going to do is for touch monitor, so i've made a new keyboard. 
The problem is that if I press a button of this keyboard, i can read the corrispondent input, but i can't read in the json array. But if i write in this input with the keyboard of computer, i can see the key pressed in the array.

Here isn't my application, it is just an easy example to show you my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/4cP2xSDRgvHG29RuA92N?p=preview

here is the jQuery of KeyBoard:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myInput').click(function() {
    $('#n_keypad').fadeToggle('fast');
  });
  $('.done').click(function() {
    $('#n_keypad').hide('fast');
  });
  $('.numero').click(function() {
    if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val())) {
      if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) === 0) {
        $('#myInput').val($(this).text());
      } else {
        $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val() + $(this).text());
      }
    }
  });
  $('.neg').click(function() {
    if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length > 0) {
      if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) > 0) {
        $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) - 1);
      }
    }
  });
  $('.pos').click(function() {
    if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length > 0) {
      $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) + 1);
    }
  });
  $('.del').click(function() {
    $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val().substring(0, $('#myInput').val().length - 1));
  });
  $('.clear').click(function() {
    $('#myInput').val('');
  });
  $('.zero').click(function() {
    if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val())) {
      if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) !== 0) {
        $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val() + $(this).text());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular insteted of jQuery.
Here is a running example. It is more easy and loosely coupled.

HTML

```
<input type="text"  data-ng-model="food.Text" data-ng-click="food.showKeypad = true" />
<keypad data-show="food.showKeypad" data-text="food.Text" />
```

JS

```
app.directive('keypad', function($compile) {
      return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          scope : {
            show : '=',
            text : '='
          },
          link : function(scope, element, attrs, model){
            scope.type = function(){
                scope.text = scope.text+'0';
            };
            scope.done = function(){
                scope.show = false;
            };
            element.parent().append($compile(
                    '<div ng-show="show">'+
                    '<button ng-click="type()">0</button>'+
                    '<button ng-click="done()">x</button>'+
                    '</div>'
            )(scope));
         }
      };
    });
```

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/h4XoEt3mI62iWp7A7nQr?p=preview)

Comment: Use template for directive if you have lots of button and create different function for different button group. One problem you will face here related to to cursor in the text box.