# Include some code in ng-repeat Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to include in ng-repeat and iterate also the virtual keyboard showing when you press on the input field? http://plnkr.co/edit/4cP2xSDRgvHG29RuA92N?p=preview 
Because for now, using jQuery, it shows just for the first input....

```
            <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="myInput"  class="form-control" data-ng-model="food.Text"/>
<table class="ui-bar-a" id="n_keypad" style="display: none; -khtml-user-select: none;">
<tr>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">7</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">8</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">9</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="del">Del</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">4</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">5</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">6</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="clear">Clear</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">1</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">2</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">3</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e">&nbsp;</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="neg">-</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="zero">0</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="pos">+</a></td>
   <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="done">Done</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe what is the problem and what you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is that the touch and virtual keyboard does not repeat when i press Add button. In fact the Add button add a new form of fields...but it doen't include the keyboard.. i would repeat also the keyboard in the input text but i'm not able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problem on you plunkar.

1. You are using Jquery to handle the event but some times using angular js also. You should use one.
2. On jquery ready method you are attaching the event. So after adding via angularjs it is not attaching the event on text field. (I Solved it with global method but it is bad practice, see my plunker)
3. You are using click event on Text field, I think you should us focus
   event.
4. Inside ng-repeat you are using id="myText" like that so those id is being repeated while adding more row. Play with css class.

I worked on the plunker and here is [mine](http://plnkr.co/edit/IErj4l6HHwu02nBOZXmr?p=preview). Though I did not solve all the above problem.

```
data-ng-click="food.showKeypad = true" //Use this on input
data-ng-show="food.showKeypad" //use this on table
//No need events for input, dont forget to remove display none from table
```

Comment: Using Angular directive answer is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214313/ng-repeat-angular-touch-keyboard